how can I compare to texts and extract only the difference text into the other cell



Column A
Column B
Column C




Iam18yearsold
Iam17yearsold
7


thereisagirl
therearegirls
are,s



I need to compare to cells and then extract only the difference to the third cell. I want to have the result like in column C and would be great if I do not need to use VBA, I use microsoft 365. Please kindly help.
I tried with substitute but it did not work because it return the whole text that difference. =Substitute(A2;B2;"")     the result Iam17yearsold. But I only want 7 for the answer.

This question on Superuser feels somewhat similar perhaps it can get you started even more.

If A contains Iam and B amI what would you expect it to return?

for this case, the best I expect it to not return anything.

And why return are for your second and not re? Since both include the a in between there and girl

oh, I'm sorry. That was a typo. You were right, that suppose to return re.

Assuming TAB, char(8), is not part of your texts to compare, using that as a delimiter:

compare characters in b with a

using 'If start_num is greater than the length of text, MID/MIDB returns "" (empty text'


replace with the delimiter if equal
split by delimiter, ignoring blanks and join

=LET(
    extract_diff, LAMBDA(a, b,
        LET(
            idx, SEQUENCE(, MAX(LEN(a), LEN(b))),
            b, MID(b, idx, 1),
            delim, CHAR(8),
            ARRAYTOTEXT(
                TEXTSPLIT(CONCAT(IF(MID(a, idx, 1) <> b, b, delim)), delim, , TRUE)
            )
        )
    ),
    MAP(A2:A3, B2:B3, extract_diff)
)


